# Max and Min of Frequency Both Returning Same Value

Tags: python, loops, max, frequency, min

I've created a GUI using wxFormBuilder that should allow a user to enter the names of "visitors to a business" into a list and then click one of two buttons to return the most frequent and least frequent visitors to the business. Here's a look at the GUI: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6GHbK.jpg

Unfortunately, both the Most and Least buttons are throwing the same value (Most). I think it has to do with how the frequencies are weighting the input and perhaps with the definition overlaps of the clkFindMost and clkFindLeast events. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit: I am extremely new to Python, and the learning curve is STEEP

```
import wx
import myLoopGUI
import commands

class MyLoopFrame(myLoopGUI.MyFrame1):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        myLoopGUI.MyFrame1.__init__(self, parent)

    def clkAddData(self,parent):
        if len(self.txtAddData.Value) != 0:
            try:
                myname = str(self.txtAddData.Value)
                self.listMyData.Append(str(myname))
            except:
                wx.MessageBox("This has to be a name!")            
        else:
            wx.MessageBox("This can't be empty")




    def clkFindMost(self, parent):
        name_list = set(self.listMyData.GetStrings())
        unique_names = set(name_list)
        frequencies = {}
        for name in unique_names:
            if frequencies.get(name):
                frequencies[name] += 1
            else:
                frequencies[name] = 0

        counts = list(frequencies.values())
        names = list(frequencies.keys())
        max_count_index = counts.index(max(counts))
        min_count_index = counts.index(min(counts))
        most_frequent = names[max_count_index]
        least_frequent = names[min_count_index]
        self.txtResults.Value = most_frequent



    def clkFindLeast(self, parent):
        name_list = set(self.listMyData.GetStrings())
        unique_names = set(name_list)
        frequencies = {}
        for name in unique_names:
            if frequencies.get(name):
                frequencies[name] += 1
            else:
                frequencies[name] = 0

        counts = list(frequencies.values())
        names = list(frequencies.keys())
        max_count_index = counts.index(max(counts))
        min_count_index = counts.index(min(counts))
        most_frequent = names[max_count_index]
        least_frequent = names[min_count_index]
        self.txtResults.Value = least_frequent

    def clkClear (self, parent):
        self.txtResults.SetValue("")

#Needed to ensure the program runs        
myApp = wx.App(False)
myFrame = MyLoopFrame(None)
myFrame.Show()
myApp.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: In my original answer I focused on the wrong problem.

To begin with, it does not make sense to iterate over a set of unique names to determine frequencies. You should instead iterate over all the names, e.g.:

```
    name_list = self.listMyData.GetStrings() # presuming this is an iterable
    frequencies = {}
    for name in name_list:
        if frequencies.get(name):
            frequencies[name] += 1
        else:
            frequencies[name] = 0
```

Even though your assignment doesn't allow it I'll leave this for edification:
An elegant solution for what you want to do is provided in `collections.defaultdict` which creates a key if it doesn't exist and increments if it does exist. Since `collections.defaultdict` subclasses `dict` the `dict` methods you use later in your code will still work.

```
import collections as co # at top of script
# ...
    name_list = self.listMyData.GetStrings() # presuming this is an iterable
    frequencies = co.defaultdict(int)
    for name in name_list:
        frequencies[name] += 1
```

Comment: Ohhhh, okay. I get it now. How can I rectify this? (like I mentioned before. I'm very new to Python)

Comment: This is excellent to know. Unfortunately, I have to maintain the for loop and the if/else construction as part of this assignment. Is there a non-"elegant" way to resolve this?

Comment: I revised my answer. The problem is that you're iterating over the unique names but you really want to iterate over the non-uniqified list.

Comment: This is awesome. Thank you so much for your help, I really appreciate it. It's awesome to have a community like this to learn from.

Comment: Cheers, mate. Happy coding to you.